# get filename from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an id from drive.google.com and I need to know the filename . It is not my drive or file but the file is publicly available . But my code throws an error :

```
// id provided
// using google drive api v3          
DriveService service = new DriveService();          
string filename = service.Files.Get(id).Execute().Name;
```

"The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Question I guess is how do I authenticate programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it:

1. Followed instructions here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/dotnet
2. The code that worked for me is slightly different though. For getting the credentials, I use :

   ```
   var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credential.json").CreateScoped(Scopes);
   ```